# TypeScript constant string cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to define a string constant rather than have to define it multiple times, my code is as follows;

```
interface RefreshReviewerBenchAction { type: 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT' }
```

I am confused as to why why this isn't of type 'string' rather than what appears to be a constant string. I try to define this constant string like this;

```
export const REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT';

interface RefreshReviewerBenchAction { type: REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT }
```

But I'm getting an error stating that "REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT cannot be found". I think it cannot be found because I am using a constant string where a type is expected. So the question is what is the difference between string and 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT'? And how do I make 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT' a string type so I don't have to use what appears to be a constant string throughout my code?

Comment: The difference in your case is that `String` is a data type, whereas `'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT'` is an actual string. It's like the difference between `Number` and `4`. One is a data type, the other is an instance of that data type. If this is for a Redux situation then an `enum` of action types is probably a simpler choice than a bunch of string constants that you coerce into types.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the problem has to do with the difference between values and types.  A given name can be independently defined as a value, a type, or both.  (A string literal like `'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT'` can be used as either a value or a type.)  Use the `typeof` keyword to get the type of the constant `REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT`:

```
export const REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT';
interface RefreshReviewerBenchAction { type: typeof REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT }
```

If you wanted to be able to use `REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT` directly as a type, then you could define a type alias:

```
export const REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT';
type REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = typeof REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT;
interface RefreshReviewerBenchAction { type: REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT }
```

Comment: `type REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = typeof REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT;` - would it work?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, try it in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT%20%3D%20'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT'%3B%0D%0Atype%20REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT%20%3D%20typeof%20REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20RefreshReviewerBenchAction%20%7B%20type%3A%20REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT%20%7D%0D%0A).

Comment: Right, it implies that `REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT` variable is declared above, it was not immediately obvious from the answer, sorry. I thought as soon as you define a `REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT` type the declaration is to go away.

Comment: It is just really confusing when this is correct
`type REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT';

interface RefreshReviewerBenchAction { type: REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT }`

and this is not

`export const actionCreators = {
    refresh: () => <RefreshReviewerBenchAction>{ type: REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT },
    componentData: componentData
};`

Comment: What is a type of 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT' mean? I understand a type of string, number etc. But 'xxxx'?

Comment: The type `'xxxx'` is a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types); the only valid value of this type is the exact string `'xxxx'`.  So your original interface definition was saying that for an object to be a valid `RefreshReviewerBenchAction`, its `type` property has to be the exact string `'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT'`.

Answer (score 0):

Fair warning, I am pretty new to Typescript, so if someone has a better solution please chime in.

I think what you are looking for is [Type Aliases](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). You create a type that is an alias for the constant value, then reference that type.

```
type REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT = 'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT';

interface RefreshReviewerBenchAction { type: REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT }
```

An implementing class is then valid if it has a `type` prop that is set to `REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT` or the string value 
`'REFRESH_REVIEWER_BENCH_COMPONENT'`, though you probably want the former.